# Autocomplete Django form jQuery

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm kind of new to Django. Anyway, I want my form to have JavaScript Autocomplete. An example of what I'm trying to do is this:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp. So, here is my question: should I go for all **HTML and JavaScript** and then try to pass the user input manually by declaring this in my views.py?

```
def register(request):
country = request.POST['mycountry']
```

Or, is there any Django way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in the past. little tricky to get up and running from what I remember. Also active on github.

http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

Comment: It's tricky for beginner. Guess I will be sticking to react as front end and django as backend